# Why does my system see 8gb ram, when I have 16gb installed

Tags: manjaro, hardware, ram

I've just assembled a new PC and I have 1 16gb plate installed, but my system reports that it has only 8gb available.

output of `inxi -m`:

```
Memory:
  RAM: total: 7.23 GiB used: 3.51 GiB (48.5%)
  Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB slots: 2 EC: None
  Device-1: DIMM 0 type: no module installed
  Device-2: DIMM 0 type: DDR4 size: 16 GiB speed: 2133 MT/s
```

output of `free -h`:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,2Gi       3,2Gi       2,5Gi        88Mi       1,5Gi       3,7Gi
Swap:          8,8Gi          0B       8,8Gi
```

output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux garnet-arch 5.15.41-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 18 09:20:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `dmidecode --type 17`:

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001E
    Error Information Handle: 0x0024
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: Unknown
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
    Memory Technology: Unknown
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Unknown
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: None
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001E
    Error Information Handle: 0x0026
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: CMSO16GX4M1A2133C15 
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 3, Hex 0x9E
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 16 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

So If I read it correctly, the system sees the 16gb plate installed on Device-2, but only 8 are seen as RAM.

Comment: that's a bit strange. You say "new PC", so I'll assume a late-generation intel core-i or  a zen/ zen 2 or later amd processor, right? What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: Please upload `dmesg` somewhere, e.g. pastebin (with an expiration date).

Comment: do you have the swap file in ramdisk?

Comment: Is the new RAM module compatible with the motherboard? Is the BIOS configured correctly to use it? Can you post the output of `dmidecode --type 17`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I've updated the question with more data.
This is a newly bought pc, and a fresh install of an the os. I'm also fairly new to linux. 
How do I check if I have a ram disk and swap file there?

Comment: Is the 16 GB RAM seen by the BIOS?

Comment: **Please** upload `dmesg` somewhere, e.g. pastebin (with an expiration date).

Comment: Perhaps 8GB has been reserved by the BIOS for the iGPU or perhaps it's been configured for some so-called acceleration mode.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov here is the output of `dmesg` thanks for looking into it https://pastebin.com/Tgq0n6wF

Comment: Also, I see lots of segfaults - could you run memtest86 ( https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm ) and 1) check whether it sees all the ram 2) run at least a single cycle of memory test?

Comment: Also, this is a laptop with Ryzen 5700U, are there any VRAM related settings in BIOS? Could be you've pre-allocated 8GB for it :-)

Comment: Here's a nice story, too bad it doesn't apply to you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655701/only-half-ram-memory-available-to-linux-in-legacy-mode-uefi-shows-full-why You're already booting in UEFI mode

Comment: @Renan i don't see RAM information in the bios at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've ran the memtest86 and on the test page it reports: 
`Memory: 7589M`, but all the tests pass

Comment: There's something wrong with your memory module or motherboard. It's a HW issue most likely. Try to reset BIOS settings just in case and see if it helps.